# How do I get to split in two places?

Tags: java, input

I would like to get something to work, a splitting in two places.

```
System.out.println( Integer.parseInt(text.getText().split("--")[1]
                    .substring((text.getText().split("--")[1]).split("x")[0])));
```

does not work. If I type `--400x55` how do I get it to print "400 , 55".

I want it to be changeable, so if the user types some different dimensions, it will use those. So how would I do this?

Comment: Will the numbers be always in the format --999x99?

Comment: Can you give a couple of examples

Comment: `"--400x55".substring(2).split("x")` The method `split()` returns an array, you should apply `Integer.parseInt()` on each member of the array separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    System.out.println(
        Integer.parseInt(
          Arrays.toString(
               text.getText().replaceAll("--","").split("x")
     )
    )
   )
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks Bswajit_86! I used `System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(text.getText().replace("--", "").split("x")[0]));
                System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(text.getText().replace("--", "").split("x")[1]));` instead of that. But that was the one to make me think of how to do that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String[] tokens = text.split("x");
System.out.println(tokens[0].split("-")[2] + " , " + tokens[1]); // tokenize by -
```

or

```
String[] tokens = text.split("x");
System.out.println(tokens[0].split("--")[1] + " , " + tokens[1]); // tokenize by --
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
String text="--400x55";
System.out.println(text.split("--")[1]); // gives you 400x55
System.out.println(text.split("--")[1].split("x")[0]); // gives you 400
System.out.println(text.split("--")[1].split("x")[1]); // gives you 55
```

Answer (score 0):

use Regular expression to split

```
"--400x55".split(/\D/)
```

it gives you ["","","400","55"]

use the above array according to your need